# Deal single/double quotes in string

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have defined a variable which consist dynamic variable

```
var tempVar = "<%=varName%>";
```

the `varName` outputs `Black/Blue Mirror + some special character with single and double quotes`. on the page it breaks the tempVar due to single/double quotes.

Actual string which varName have is `Black/Blue Mirror ? /\,.°º®#&*@+–!:()‘’”"'`. This is actually allowed in my project.

Output in the page: `var tempVar = "Black/Blue Mirror ? /\,.°º®#&*@+–!:()‘’”"'";`

Comment: and your question is ??

Comment: Hope you understand my question now

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
[..]
var tempVar = <c:out value="${varName}"/>;
```

It will change double quotes into `&quot;` etc.

If `varName` is declared inside a scriptlet, you must make it visible to Expression Language:

```
<%
    pageContext.setAttribute("varName", varName);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace double quotes with `\"`

Then Javascript will read them as double quote.

```
var tempVar = "<%=varName.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")%>";
```